# Angular without route navigate

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider two page - page1 and page2 . I am at page1 controlled by me so on the click of button on page1 I will be navigating to page2. but the control of page2 is not with me. So I wanted to know if their is a option where once the task completed in page2 which I don't have control, I can come to page1??

Comment: If you don't have control over page 2 you have to ask whoever is responsible for page 2 to implement this redirect. Since you don't have control over page 2 you can't navigate back.

Comment: You should try to find out if you can provide a return url or a webhook to page2 which they will utilize to send the user back to page1. If they don't have this functionality there's nothing you can do until they implement it.